# Series expansion for $\frac{1}{x+1}$ in terms of $\frac{1}{x-1}$

Tags: series-expansion

I would like to expand a function as
$$\frac{1}{x+1} = \frac{1}{x-1+2} = \frac{1}{x-1} \frac{1}{ 1+\frac{2}{x-1}}  = \frac{1}{x-1} \left[ 1- \frac{2}{x-1} + \left(\frac{2}{x-1}\right)^2  + \cdots \right]$$

I tried

> Series[1/(x + 1), {x, Infinity + 1, 3}]

apprently it does not work. Is there any robust way to realize this kind of expansion? Assume $|x|$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question but here is a workaround: Series[Unevaluated[1/((x - 1) + 2)] /. HoldPattern[x -     1] -> t, {t, 
   Infinity, 3}] /. t -> (x - 1)}

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get a solution, 1/(x + 1) /. x -> t + 1;
Series[%, {t, Infinity, 3}];
% /. t -> x - 1

Answer (score 4):

This is your expression:

```
expr1 = 1/(x + 1);
```

This is the the change of variables:

```
 sl = Solve[x - 1 == z, x][[1, 1]]

    (*  x -> 1 + z  *)
```

Substituted to the expression it yields this:

```
expr2 = expr1 /. sl

(*  1/(2 + z)   *)
```

Now it can be expaneded as you need:

```
Series[expr1 /. sl, {z, Infinity, 5}] /. z -> HoldForm[x - 1]

(*    
SeriesData[
HoldForm[x - 1], 
DirectedInfinity[1], {1, -2, 4, -8, 16}, 1, 6, 1]   *)
```

Just try